# How to have batch file code only copy the most recent .bak file from a directory

Tags: file, batch-file, copy

I recently had very kind assistance on how to make the below code copy the most recent file from a file on my C:\ called 'C:! BATCH'

It's transpired that I now need to have the batch file only look for .bak files in this dorectory, and while I'm positive this is a relatively simple tweak, I've so far had no luck on finding how this is done.

Any advice on this would be very much appreciated, many thanks!

```
@echo off
pushd C:\! BATCH
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%G in ('dir/b/od') do (set newest=%%G)
copy "!newest!" C:\DROP\
PAUSE
```

Comment: In StackOverflow is customary to accept the answer that provided the solution to your problem and perhaps upvote it. You accept an answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answser so it turns solid green. You can upvote an answer by clicking the arrow indicating up near to the vote count to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> I now need to have the batch file only
>   look for .bak files in this directory.

The change is simply adding `*.bak` to the `dir` command.

```
@echo off

pushd c:\BATCH\

setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%G in ('dir/b/od *.bak') do (set newest=%%G)

copy "!newest!" c:\DROP\look for .bak files in this dorectory
```